# Laravel 5 application with Integrated Blogging

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, blogs

I am in the middle of designing a website which will be built on Laravel and include a blogging module.

At the moment I am trying to decide if I should either:

1) Install WordPress in a sub directory and handle the blogging through WP.
2) Write the code from scratch so the blogging module is purely built on Laravel.

I am aware that there may be other alternatives, and if any of you have had experience with them please point me in their direction.

If I were to opt for option 2. What would be some important considerations I should factor in before going ahead?

**EDIT**
By important considerations i mean this:

I am not overly bothered about time to implement. What I want to know is why would you choose a WordPress blog over a custom built blog from the customers point of view and SEO point of view. What does WordPress add to blog posts for example that I wouldn't be able to do quite simply my self?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a deep integration of the blog into your project, I think it's better to choose a Laravel solution, leaving Wordpress.

There are some well-made modules for blogging, for example [Blogify](http://www.blogify.io/), just search on the internet. Or buid it from your own.

Comment: Thank you. I think the Laravel route is better. Partly because I actually enjoy coding in Laravel and not WordPress. I have searched for packages and Blogify did appeal to me. The only reason I am unsure is the owner states - "Due to the fact that there are better alternatives on the market and a lack of time I will no longer maintain the Blogify package."

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd probably go with option #1 purely to save time, UNLESS:

1. The template between the Laravel app and the WP Blog need to be the same, as updating BOTH templates for future changes (even just menu edits) gets annoying, or
2. The two applications need to share users between each other.. cuz that would be a pain the butt to setup.

Alternatively, I'm sure there's some pre-built Laravel blog modules out there somewhere if you decided to go with option #2.

Comment: The two applications will need to share users between each other in the future yes. Which is the main thing really putting me off WordPress. I am about to add another consideration to my original post. Please check back.